# Use Rails link_to tag with Bootstrap accordion dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

How could I replace the following with a Rails `link_to` tag, while still using HAML?

```
%a{"aria-controls" => "collapseOne", "aria-expanded" => "true", "data-parent" => "#accordion", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :href => "#collapseOne", :role => "button"}
      Collapsible Group Item #1
```

This is from a Bootstrap accordion example, except using HAML instead of HTML: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really HAML anymore, it's just the `link_to` helper...  Try this:

```
= link_to 'Collapsible Group Item #1', '#collapseOne', role: :button,
          data: { parent: '#accordion', toggle: :collapse },
          aria: { controls: :collapseOne, expanded: true }
```